# Waiting for a UIView to finish

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios7

```
[_articleTxtView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:_fontSizeInt]];
[_articleTxtView layoutIfNeeded];
[_articleTxtView sizeToFit];
```

The above code is triggered with a press of a UIButton and responsible of changing the size of a UITextView. Every time the UIButton is pressed the _fontSizeInt changes to a bigger number and the `UITextView` height changes accordingly.

The problem is that `layoutIfNeeded` and `sizeToFit`are called before setFont is finished and cuts `UITextView` in the middle.

Possible solutions:

This solution works great but I'd preffer not using something with such a bad practice.

```
..
    [_articleTxtView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[DataManager sharedDataManager].fontSize]];        
    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01]; 
}

- (void)test
{
    [_articleTxtView layoutIfNeeded];
    [_articleTxtView sizeToFit];
}
```

I thought about using the next code but for some reason it doesn't always work. Also I'm not sure if that's a proper use of the animation block (there's really no animation involved):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^()
     {
         [_articleTxtView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[DataManager sharedDataManager].fontSize]];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [_articleTxtView layoutIfNeeded];
         [_articleTxtView sizeToFit];
     }];
```

Is there a better way to let a method "know" when a UIView finished painting \ loading?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could implement viewDidLoad (called once) or viewWillAppear (called every time) in the articleTxtView view controller class

Comment: articleTxtView is a UIView, and viewDidLoad is a UIView Controller method. Also, viewDidLoad is only called once. Why / how would this work?

Comment: Right, I meant in it's view controller.
Try viewDidAppear then, it's called every time the view (so the text view) appears
(answer edited) does this helps ?